# Dropbox Chooser for folders

Tags: android, dropbox, dropbox-api

Is there a way to have a chooser like this but for folders instead of files? I'm using the Core API [image: screen]

Comment: See what appears to be the same question on the Dropbox API forum: https://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=112250&replies=2#post-594993.

Comment: @smarx The link is not correct

Comment: Sorry, the old forum is gone. The short answer is "No."

Comment: @smarx It sucks to know :-( And please mention @ Nabin to notify me